# Using an Android resources efficiently

Tags: android, resources

I'm trying to figure out how to use Android's resource system efficiently, both to provide the highest resolution resources and to keep the .apk size low.

My resource folders:

```
drawable-normal-mdpi
drawable-normal-hdpi
drawable-large-mdpi
```

Now the way I'm using the resources (a game) the normal-hdpi and large-mdpi are exactly the same. I don't want to include both in my final .apk because its going to inflate the size unnecessarily.  Is there a way to get around this? I tried to use a symbolic link (linux) but the android tools follow the links and copy the resources.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the proper way to set my drawable directories to support the new Dell Streak without losing support for older devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903708/what-is-the-proper-way-to-set-my-drawable-directories-to-support-the-new-dell-st)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for an [AliasResource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources).

Comment: This solution is far from ideal but would solve the problem. So for each resource I'm going to have to place them in the default folder with a descriptive name like car_noraml_and_large and reference that drawable from within the drawable-normal-hdpi and drawable-large-mdpi in additional files by `android:src="@drawable/car_normal_and_large` This is going to be unmanageable for anything but a small number of files. Time to write a python script I suppose...

Comment: You can also just specify a default resource, which will be used for every configuration for which you don't provide one.

Comment: True we could leverage that also. By just using the `drawable` folder will the system try and scale the resources? (because I don't want it to) In that case should I use the `drawable-nodpi` folder?

Comment: For those wondering, I ended up creating a python script to rename the images and create the xml files for me