# What is the proper way to set my drawable directories to support the new Dell Streak without losing support for older devices?

Tags: android

This seems to be a [widespread problem](http://blog.alsutton.com/2010/07/03/android-tablets-and-mdpi-large/).

I have the following drawable directories:

```
drwxr-xr-x  18 mike  staff   612 Feb  4 17:28 drawable/
drwxr-xr-x  51 mike  staff  1734 Feb  4 17:32 drawable-nodpi/
drwxr-xr-x  44 mike  staff  1496 Feb  4 17:30 drawable-normal-mdpi/
```

My xml drawable resources are in drawable.  My resources intended for the large-mdpi (Dell Streak) and normal-hdpi (Droid, Nexus, Incredible, etc.) are all in drawable-nodpi.  My resources for normal-mdpi (older phones like the G1) are in drawable-normal-mdpi.

Unfortunately, the normal-hdpi phones like the Droid are pulling their resources from drawable-normal-mdpi instead of from drawable-nodpi.  This is likely because of the rules in [How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html).

So the question is, how do I provide support for large-mdpi devices like the Streak along with normal-hdpi devices like the Droid, as well as normal-mdpi devices like the G1?

The simplest solution would probably be to make two copies of my large resources, one in normal-hdpi for the droid and one in large-mdpi for the streak, but i'd like to avoid duplicating all of these resources.

*Update*

Per Mayra's suggestion, I could make an alias for every resource.  However, there are a lot of resources I'd have to make aliases for, which would make maintenance a nightmare going forward, so I'm hoping for another solution.

Comment: commonsguy seems to suggest implementing a [build tool](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/bRzcZ-wbYgM/5jZ1nJRpuE8J) to accomplish this, but hopefully there's another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Rename your "drawable-nodpi" to "drawable-nodpi-800x480" (the nodpi needs to be in there, or it wont work!) and</strike> rename "drawable-normal-mdpi" to "drawable-480x320".

Comment: But then wouldn't I also need to make a copy of drawable-nodpi-800x480 for 854x480 devices?

Comment: Yes, I didn't think of the WVGA854. I did some testing, though. If you leave the "drawable-nodpi" as it is, and just change the "drawable-normal-mdpi" to "drawable-480x320" it should work the way you want it to. I confirmed it with WVGA800, WVGA854 and HVGA emulators.

Comment: I will try this.  Anyone see any problems with this solution?  Are there any devices that report 320x480 instead of 480x320, for example?  I hate to make my resources specific to a particular resolution, but maybe that's the way to go?

Comment: @emmby Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) document. In table 1 you see that -normal-mdpi always has the HVGA (320x480) resolution. The difference between -normal-mdpi and -480x320 is, that the normal keyword doesn't appear in the later. The screen size keywords (like small, normal, large) have a very high priority in androids resource matching. In your case this keyword makes all devices using normal screens use this resource, no matter if they are mdpi or not. 480x320 and 320x480 are the same, because of landscape / portrait mode.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this seems to work on hvga-mdpi, hvga-hdpi, and wvga-mdpi.  Thanks Chris!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alias resource to provide a pointer to the resource without copying it.  See [Alias Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources)

Comment: Yes, although my understanding is that I'd have to do that for every resource in the directory.  The are dozens there, and the consequences of forgetting one or two are not easy to detect (it's not fail fast), so it'd be nice to have a more reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the HDPI resources in just the `drawable` folder and not `drawable-nodpi`?

Comment: No, but doing that would mean they would get auto scaled up by 150% on hdpi devices, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same [question 2 days before you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869831/using-an-android-resources-effeciently) and the closest thing to a solution was using the alias resource (via Mayra). I ended up writing a python script to handle this for me. Its a really bad work around and I wish I had enough determination to create a more fool proof solution.

Just for reference, the shared resources belong in a `nodpi` folder so they aren't scaled by android.

Answer (score -1):

Check this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Basically, you should put your drawables in drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, etc. and your layout files in layout-small, layout-medium, etc. directories. So, layouts should be *screen size* dependent and drawables should be *screen density* dependent.

Comment: That's good advice, thank you.  However, I'm not sure this solves the problem.  I want the same drawables to be used on the Nexus S (for example) and the Dell Streak.  The former is hdpi and the latter is mdpi.  As asked in the question, how does one avoid duplicating the drawables?  The stuff about layouts is interesting but perhaps tangential.